# What is the algorithm for "blindness"?

Tags: cryptography

Suppose I want to develop a IM application, and I want to ensure my users that I will not obtain their conversation information, that is, prove by a algorithm that I don't know about something.

How can I do that? Is their something similar to public-key method to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is a solvable problem as long as the application you provide is a black box to the user. The way to achieve what you want is to provide the source code to your client so that the user can inspect it and potentially compile it themselves. For example, consider [Tarsnap](https://www.tarsnap.com/download.html), which is targeting exactly this kind of problem (they provide online backups "for the truly paranoid"). The Tarsnap client is *only* provided in source form.

You can provide a similar (but weaker) assurance by publishing your protocol specification without publishing the source code to your implementation. This allows the user to inspect the protocol, determine whether it sends data that could be read in transit, and potentially implement their own client to protect themselves from any side-channels that might exist in your client.

The overarching rule is that cryptography is best done in public. Each piece of your system that is secret is a piece that the user must implicitly trust you on and cannot prove your behavior. The fewer secrets you enforce, the more trustworthy you can be.

Ultimately, however, I do not believe it is possible to prove that Eve does not know something. It is only possible to prove that Eve cannot discover something given that she stays within some set of rules.

As a quick proof by counter-example:

- Alice sends message M to Bob using a provably-secure transform E(K,M).
- Eve intercepts E(K,M), but since it is provably-secure, and she does not have K, she cannot decrypt it.
- Eve begins dating Bob and convinces him to tell her K.
- Eve performs D(K,E(K,M)) and recovers M.
- Therefore, E(K,M) does not prove blindness over all possible attacks, despite being provably-secure over traditional attacks.